# Android query NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, nullpointerexception

i need help with this
I got a null pointer Exception here is my classes :

usersBDD.java

```
private static final String TABLE_USERS = "utilisateurs";
UsersBDD dbUser = new UsersBDD(this);
dbUser.open();
String[] columns = new String[] { COL_NOM, COL_PROFIL, COL_TEL, COL_EMAIL, COL_ADRESSE };
Cursor cursor = bdd.query(TABLE_USERS, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Tab1Activity.java

```
public SQLiteDatabase bdd;

    private MaBaseSQLite maBaseSQLite;

    public UsersBDD(Context context){
        //On créer la BDD et sa table
        maBaseSQLite = new MaBaseSQLite(context, NOM_BDD, null, VERSION_BDD);
    }

    public void open(){
        //on ouvre la BDD en écriture

        bdd = maBaseSQLite.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

Below is my StackTrace

---

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-17 12:26:30.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1542): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ma.cfconsult.CfConsult/ma.cfconsult.CfConsult.Menu}:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ma.cfconsult.CfConsult/ma.cfconsult.CfConsult.Tab1Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
09-17 12:26:30.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736) 
09-17 12:26:30.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1542): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
```

–

Comment: Can you add the exception stack trace?

Comment: I think you open database for read then you have use getReadableDatabase() instead of getWritableDatabase().

Comment: no it's getWritabledatabase()

Comment: how can i put the logs here ? it's too long

Comment: Put only the relevant part: look for `FATAL EXCEPTION` and include the exception stacktrace below.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 12:26:30.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ma.cfconsult.CfConsult/ma.cfconsult.CfConsult.Menu}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ma.cfconsult.CfConsult/ma.cfconsult.CfConsult.Tab1Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 12:26:30.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
09-17 12:26:30.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)

Comment: i noticed that i have a problem with my query

Comment: Edit the question and post the stacktrace as a codeblock and not as a comment.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 12:26:30.495: E/AndroidRuntime(1542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ma.cfconsult.CfConsult/ma.cfconsult.CfConsult.Menu}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ma.cfconsult.CfConsult/ma.cfconsult.CfConsult.Tab1Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException